# hideSoftInputFromWindow not working?

Tags: android

For some `EditText` views I want to use a custom keyboard instead of the *soft* one.

The problem is when I click on an `EditText` for the first time both keyboards are shown. When I click for the second time - the soft keyboard finally disappeares.

What might be the reason for such behavior?

Here's the code I use:

```
package pkleczek.profiwan.keyboards;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;

public abstract class CustomKeyboard {

    /** A link to the KeyboardView that is used to render this CustomKeyboard. */
    protected KeyboardView mKeyboardView;
    /** A link to the activity that hosts the {@link #mKeyboardView}. */
    protected Activity mHostActivity;

    /** Returns whether the CustomKeyboard is visible. */
    public boolean isCustomKeyboardVisible() {
        return mKeyboardView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
    }

    /**
     * Make the CustomKeyboard visible, and hide the system keyboard for view v.
     */
    public void showCustomKeyboard(View v) {
        mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mKeyboardView.setEnabled(true);

        if (v != null) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) mHostActivity
                    .getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

    /** Make the CustomKeyboard invisible. */
    public void hideCustomKeyboard() {
        mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mKeyboardView.setEnabled(false);
    }

    /**
     * Register <var>EditText<var> with resource id <var>resid</var> (on the
     * hosting activity) for using this custom keyboard.
     * 
     * @param resid
     *            The resource id of the EditText that registers to the custom
     *            keyboard.
     */
    public void registerEditText(int resid) {
        EditText edittext = (EditText) mHostActivity.findViewById(resid);

        edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    showCustomKeyboard(v);
                } else {
                    hideCustomKeyboard();
                }
            }
        });

        edittext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showCustomKeyboard(v);
            }
        });

        edittext.setInputType(edittext.getInputType()
                | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Try to put the following condition in your **InputMethodManager** code before `inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);`line:

```
    if (inputManager!=null) {
                Activity activity = getActivity();
                if (acvivity == null)
                    return;
                if (activity.getCurrentFocus() == null)
                    return;
                if (activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken() == null)
                    return;
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
```

I used it in **ListFragment** to hide the default keyboard. First when i press an **EditText** and keyboard is shown and when on **onScrollStateChanged** i hide it.

You can also try to put the **InputMethodManager** code inside the onClickListener of the **EditText** and then call your **showCustomKeyboard()** method.

Put an **Else** statement and **Log** in it after the `if (v != null)`, maybe your `View v` is **null**.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists.
I've checked it with debugger and all `hideSoftInputFromWindow()` methods were called.

Comment: Try to use `setOnTouchListener()` instead of `setOnClickListener()` for your **EditText**. Put **Log** in your methods, this will show you best if they are actually called.

Comment: Huh.. No progress. Log shows that all methods are called, but still the soft keyboard disappeares only after I click `EditText` for the second time...

Comment: Hi, `activity` can never be `null` :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by *Rotemmiz* in the topic [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) worked for me.

An abstract:

```
public void setEditTextFocus(EditText editText, boolean isFocused)
{
    editText.setCursorVisible(isFocused);
    editText.setFocusable(isFocused);
    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(isFocused);

    if (isFocused)
    {
        editText.requestFocus();
    }
}
```